# Is there any feasible real sounding science sci-fi explanation for a chronovisor?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, time-travel, time

What would be able to explain a visor like device that can see the past or future? I'm trying to make it as little as clarketech as possible. Any ideas?

Comment: How does the wearer see the past or future? Is it akin to an augmented reality device that overlays what the wearer currently sees with that same point-of-view at a predetermined point in time? Or does it display something more akin to media content, like a static image or video of something in the past or future?

How far into the past or future can it see? And lastly, does it have to be absolute, or can it be predictive?

Comment: You can see the near past with a smartphone and lots of security cams.

Comment: My glasses let me see the past. Granted it's the very, very near past.

Answer (score 6):

Wormholes. That's the usual answer for time-shifted phenomena. Admittedly the wormholes have to be created prior to viewing either the past or future. This is the conventional description of wormholes and how they might be used.

However, the best example of using wormholes to observe both the past and future was in the science-fiction novel *The Light of Other Days* (2000) by Arthur C Clarke and Stephen Baxter. After all, if you want clarketech, why not borrow from the Clarke himself.

The Clarke-Baxter wormholes were extracted from the quantum foam, IIRC, and originally used as ubiquitous peepholes to spy on people everywhere. Only later did they discover the other wormhole mouth could open into other times. Their novel focused on observing the past, but, in principle, if you possessed the technology to open a wormhole here and now and where and when the other mouth of the wormhole opened. The observing both the past and future would be possible.

The chances are that the machinery for generating wormholes will be large, clumsy and immobile. The one or more sets of mouths of the wormholes could be attached to a visor to enable observing the past or future, This assumes that the other sets of wormhole mouths are in the same relative spatial location as the visor-wearer who can use them to look through to see either the past or the future.

Answer (score 2):

I upvote a4's wormhole tech; but note that a wormhole could be small enough (atom sized or molecule sized) to just let a stream of photons through.

In such a case, the visor is just a regular LCD display; the real scifi tech is a mechanism moving the atom-sized wormhole in the fourth dimension to change the stream of photons being received.

I would also note that seeing a "one and only" future, as opposed to "the most probable" future, would create an inherent paradox. If there is only one possible future (Einstein's Block Universe, also Newton's implied belief), then observing it and being aware of it cannot change anything at all about how the observer thinks or acts. They cannot act to change the one and only future, even to avoid their own death. The future cannot be changed for the same reason your past cannot be changed without producing a different "you".

So if anybody sees the one and only future, they were destined to see it and seeing it is part of the prerequisite for making what they saw come to pass.

Either that, or the future is malleable and all we can see (like we already do, albeit with some error, using our brains) is *possible* futures, and preferably the most likely of them.

Comment: As a technicality, the observer of the one possible future can only change the future in ways which are consistent with their observations.  If they observe their own death, they know that, at the very least, the set of photons they observed through the wormhole which they perceived to be their death must go through that wormhole.  Although you remind me of a mythos I heard in a movie a long time back which permitted an oracle to see the future by gouging out their own eyes.  The only problem was that they could see their own death, and it was impossible for a mere human to

Comment: do anything but fixate on their own death.

Comment: *...then observing it and being aware of it cannot change anything at all about how the observer thinks or acts.* Oh, yes it can. It's merely restricted to causing changes consistent with the observed future. I.e., generating self-fulfilling prophecies.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Fair enough; I should have said *cannot change their future*, which is subtly different. If there is only one future, then by induction there is only one past --- because all past states were once in the one and only future! Which means what will be, between now and the future, is exactly one path (because there is only one future starting 1 nanosecond from now). If their actions change because they saw the future, that was always destined to happen, even before they saw the future. They were destined to see the future, too. Perhaps that makes it more clear. Or muddies it up!

Answer (score 2):

**Past: echoes.**
I read a scifi which started with the narrator watching a film in a little theater.  It was of a battle between US Cavalry and American Indians.  It was unusual in that it was silent, no exposition, some recurring characters in that you would see the same people more than once, but no discernible plot.  The film ended with a shot from above of the dead and wounded on the battlefield.

This film had been made with a special camera and the inventors were hoping to make a living with it making movies.  The idea is that an event leaves lasting echo-like traces in a region which continue to produce emissions, like light.  These can be captured by a cameralike device and translated into images.  Of course a given area will have an enormous number of overlying echo traces producing their emission.  One can distinguish them by emission strength - so for example the emissions generated by me scratching my belly in this chair 10 minutes ago would be stronger (or different in character somehow?  Distinguishable!) from those emissions generated when I scratched my belly in this chair last week.

The premise of lasting, perceptible changes on a place caused by events happening in that place is also explored in Stranger in a Strange Land (Heinlein); the Martians can perceive these echoes and so abandon their cities after a while after the buildup of these traces becomes overwhelming.

**Future: foreshadows**  Future is even more of a stretch because there are many possible futures.  I really liked the movie Next with Nick Cage because that was the scifi premise: he could see the possibles in the very near future and steer via his own actions towards the one he wanted.  If you have seen it you can enjoy this awesome scene where he picks the future in which he does not get shot.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RC5ZiK6o7uQ&t=80s  If you have not seen it, go see it.

Here is how it could be done.  Imagine they have the camera that can see the past, as described above.  Somehow (accidentally?) they get it running backwards / reverse polarity and become aware that there are an enormous number of traces they did not pick up before.  By sorting them out and viewing them they become aware that they are viewing possible futures, with some signal character signifying not only how temporally distant they are (as with the past echoes) but also how likely they are.

Answer (score 0):

For the future this is really tough. I think the best you could do with hard sci-fi would be something with an AI and an immense amount of computational power behind it. Some future things would be easy to predict based on past patterns and so with some accuracy you could "see" the near future.

The past would be easier since we already see into the past, it's just such a short time that for all practical purposes it's the present. Not sure if this fits your requirements but I once read a short story with a window that had a bunch of internal reflection and then when the light finally got out it was several minutes later and so the window effectively showed the past. Obviously it's not totally plausible but it might be a start.

Another idea might be having a visor keyed into a series of far away mirrors(light-minutes) and seeing what was being reflected a few minutes ago. This has the drawback of being really hard to see anything useful since anything smaller than a large bomb going off would be too small to see.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a similar answer, but I want to focus on one aspect in particular: If your visors speak with each other - which will be the case if tech develops the way it does right now - one can make good predictions through extrapolation.

Since you have not specified how far into the past or future you are talking about, I'm gonna assume it doesn't matter and I will go with a couple of seconds/maybe a minute:

A super fast computer could extrapolate the future and past - given a number of snapshots to get the momentum and position of surrounding objects in space. 
I believe the demands on the hardware and software are pretty clear, if not - please comment.

Of course the more snapshots you take, the bigger the area around a certain object - the better you can construct the past and future. So multiple visors from multiple people/drones/whatever should be connected and work  together.

Is this super useful in real life? Probably not, but it can be a cool tool in a story, maybe a detective one.

Another possibility along this line of course is the same device again, but this time it reads the memories and thoughts of the user and due to centuries of research, it can extrapolate the decisions made by people. Imagine your best friend tells you she will buy a car, but you know that from past experiences she is kind of a talker. A device could again read from your past experiences and create possible future scenarios. So what is the advantage compared to not having a visor? Once again - connections to other visors.

If 3 people are working on that, everyone adds a piece to the story and at the end the visors are able to paint a much clearer picture. If one of them has a lot of experiences in life, the extrapolation could be quite far into future/past - of course with certain errors. The more people, the smaller the errors. This could help reconstruct catastrophes/crimes or help predict future events and help make decisions. In a way it is a better way to communicate with somewhat less bias and such.

So coming back to your friend: You connect with her husband and also her own visor (assuming she is ok with it or you can do this unnoticed) - and with that much information, the visor network is almost sure that she means it this time and will actually buy a car. Given that this is the future, most likely a flying one. Since they also have something like the internet and therefor know the current supply of the cars, can take a guess at the money available, predict personal taste, "future google" search history and so on, the prediction might even be accurate enough so that it narrows it down to a single model.

Yes, what I did doesn't actually see into the past or future and rather predicts it, but I believe it is actually possible and it is clearly aimed at something or someone, so you have well defined parameters if you want to see the future/past of a specific location/person/whatever.

Answer (score 0):

### Easy - You Already Can

Are you familiar with how computers generate images on your screen (i.e. bitmaps)?

If so, skip to "Instead of 9x9".

If not --

A screen has little dots, if zero (0) then it is black, if (1) then it is white (or visa-versa depending upon computer).

If you have color, then you can have many numbers for each pixel.

But, let's stick to black and white.

This is plus sign: "+"

```
000000000
000010000
000010000
000010000
011111110
000010000
000010000
000010000
000000000
```

If we flatten the rows, it becomes a large binary number:
000000000000010000000010000000010000011111110000010000000010000000010000000000000

In decimal, this is: 147862763372680323072

So, on a 9x9 screen, the "+" sign is just a number:  147862763372680323072

What about this number?  17454747090944

It is this in binary: 000000000000000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000000000000000000000000000

Which is this on a 9x9 screen:  (the "-" sign.)

```
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
011111110
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
```

**Instead of 9x9**

Consider this:  Instead of a 9x9 screen, use the width and height and color depth of your monitor.

NOW: Count from 0 (all balck) to 2^(widthxheightxcolor) (all white) on your screen.

*In doing so, you will generate every image that the human race has ever seen, currently does see, ever will see and could ever dream of seeing.*

**In other words, all of reality, all of possibility, alternate universes and past, present and future for each,  already exist and can be viewed - now - with TODAY'S technology.**

The only problem is how to navigate - putting the images in "time order" and finding images in your space/time.

You can then say that computer experts figured out the algorithm to find and view any space-time coordinate in any universe and in any reality and the chronovisor displays the images in the correct order - forward/backward/sideways.

Comment: Basically hand-wave it away.  What you're proposing sounds like translating a space-time coordinate directly into an image.